# Edited template of TreeView

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am working on WPF application. I have edited template of `TreeView` control and added a button to the template.

Adding this control to the window works fine and displays the button, but how to trigger button click event or command in my window?

Comment: Post your XAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer assuming that you are trying to run a `command` in the `WindowVM` from inside the `DataTemplate` of `TreeView` in view.

```
Command="{Binding DataContext.MyCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MyWindow}}}"
```